# Declare your javascript method before DOM ready

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom, dropdown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls8Ya.jpg)
I'm a javascript/html newbie. I'm wondering what this exactly means and why it needs to be done. Won't declaring javascript method anywhere inside the page allow the javascript method to be ready before the dom is ready?

On a side note: I've had issues getting a javascript method to the execute on the onchange event of an ASP.net dropdownlist control, and I'm wondering if it is because the javascript method is declared near the end of the page, after the dropdownlist control is instantiated.

The dropdownlist and javascript function is on a content page, i dont know if that would make a difference regarding the javascript, when it does a postback and has to be placed on the master page.

Comment: I think that's just for jsfiddle but check back for other responses. I'm always playing with that to get script to work at the right time too. It shouldn't really be a problem with the ddl control, but I suppose it could depend, and that's a separate issue requiring a proper question with code.

Comment: The difference is only important if your JS immediately attempts to access the DOM.  If you declare a function that accesses the DOM, but don't call it until after the DOM has loaded, you should be fine.  The key point is to delay accessing the DOM until after its loaded.